# Динамическое добавление однотипных элементов Android

Tags: android, listview

Доброго времени суток! Есть активити, в которой редактируется контакт - ФИО, фото и один или несколько номеров телефона. Вопрос касается именно телефонов - нужно динамически добавлять/удалять строки с ними и как-то потом обрабатывать. Есть какие-то стандартные методы работы с такой задачей? Возможно, телефоны как-то легко можно о собрать в массив или еще какие-то хитрости, кроме прямолинейного addView?

Answer (score 0):

Я бы, на Вашем месте, посмотрел в сторону `RecyclerView`. Это список с возможностью динамически добавлять элементы, при чем с красивой стандартной информацией.

О нем Вы можете почитать [тут](https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html?hl=ru).

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ. `RecyclerView` я использую на основной activity для хранения всех контактов. Это корректно использовать его на экране редактирования отдельного контакта как элемент `ListView`?

Comment: @I.Shelkovnikov, `Recycler` в `List`?) Я бы так делать не стал. Лучше сделайте обычное окно или диалог, в котором будет информация + `Recycler` для номеров.